# Модель бутылки

Tags: c++, opengl

Очень надо нарисовать фигуру бутылки или вроде того в OpenGL.

Answer (score 8):

1. Нарисуйте на листе бумаги в клеточку профиль бутылки.
2. Отбросьте одну половину (бутылка ведь симметричная?).
3. Разбейте профиль на прямые отрезки опорными точками. В местах сильных изгибов точек нужно побольше, на гладких участках - поменьше.
4. Поздравляю, вы произвели аппроксимацию кривой. Теперь определите координаты точек в удобной системе координат (с началом отсчета в центре донышка например).
5. Забейте в программу массив координат опорных точек. Выделите еще один массив такой же размерности (назовем его временным), но оставьте его пустым.
6. Теперь будем вращать наш профиль. Выберите количество граней у бутылки `n`. Тогда шаг поворота у нас будет `360/n` градусов.
7. Далее берёте по порядку координаты 2х соседних точек из массива, поворачиваете их на вышеупомянутый угол вокруг вертикальной оси, получаете 2 новые координаты. Рисуете полигон через эти 4 точки. 2 вычисленные координаты сохраняете во временный массив. Повторяете процедуру для всех отрезков. Т.к. во временном массиве будут результаты предыдущих вычислений, для всех отрезков кроме первого нужно будет рассчитывать только по одной точке. Когда все отрезки обработаны, меняем местами временный и основной массивы. Новый временный - очищаем.
8. Повторяете пункт 7 для всех граней от 1 до n.

---

Если идти глубже, то правильнее сначала получить координаты все опорных вершин в виде 2х-мерного массива (чтобы не пересчитывать их каждый раз при отрисовке), а потом уже выводить в нужном месте.

Comment: Напомнило: https://youtu.be/iRkZcTg1JWU?t=54m31s (необходимо включить субтитры).